# How do I find the sha256 hash of text on a Mac?

Tags: terminal

I found tutorials on how to find the sha256 hash of files, but cannot seem to find one on simple text (not a text file). Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can echo the text and pipe it to `shasum`. You'll want to use the `-a 256` option to calculate sha256:

Thanks to JMY1000 in the comments: Since `echo` adds a newline by default, `-n` should probably be added in order to get the proper shasum of the text without this newline.

```
echo -n "simple text" | shasum -a 256
```

If you want to get the hash value for a text which is already open in an editor, copy it to the clipboard and run

```
pbpaste | shasum -a 256
```